# Using str_replace with array gives unexpected results

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, str-replace

I have an array of IDs stored in a database, something like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7, etc.

I have a group of labels I am trying to apply to these numbers for use later on, but my output isn't showing what I expect.  For instance, I have this:

```
$ids[0] = 7, $ids[1] = 4
```

I use this to apply the labels:

```
$ids = str_replace('7', '1Mbps Internet', $ids);
$ids = str_replace('4', '2Mbps Internet', $ids);
$ids = str_replace('1', '3Mbps Internet', $ids);
$ids = str_replace('8', 'Commercial Internet', $ids);
$ids = str_replace('12', 'Tower Friends', $ids);
$ids = str_replace('6', 'Cable TV', $ids);
$ids = str_replace('11', 'Cable TV Basic', $ids);
$ids = str_replace('5', 'VOIP', $ids);
$ids = str_replace('10', 'Web Services', $ids);
```

However, my output is looking like this:

```
3Mbps InternetMbps Internet, 2Mbps Internet
```

When it should come out like this:

```
1Mbps Internet, 2Mbps Internet
```

---

```
$Package1 = $ids[0]; 
$Package2 = $ids[1];
$Package3 = $ids[2];
$Package4 = $ids[3];

if (!$Package1) {$P_word = "$Package:"; $Packages = "None Subscribed";}
else if ($Package1 && !$Package2) {$P_Word = "Package:"; $Packages = "$Package1";}
else if ($Package1 && $Package2 && !$Package3) {$P_Word = "Packages:"; $Packages = "$Package1, $Package2";}
else if ($Package1 && $Package2 && $Package3 && !$Package4) {$P_Word = "Packages:"; $Packages = "$Package1, $Package2, $Package3"; }
else {$P_Word = "Packages:"; $Packages = "$Package1, $Package2, $Package3, $Package4"; }
```

Comment: Can you specify your exact code and desired output?

Comment: *However, my output is looking like this:* -- output of what? Show us the part where it actually outputs your data.

Comment: The output prints the value of $Packages in the HTML code below the PHP code. The output is  the $Packages variable as set in the if/else

Answer (score 3):

`str_replace()` is a basic search. Part of your issue is how you expect PHP to search your string. For example,

```
$ids = str_replace('7', '1Mbps Internet', $ids);
$ids = str_replace('4', '2Mbps Internet', $ids);
$ids = str_replace('1', '3Mbps Internet', $ids);
```

On the 3rd line, you are searching for the string "1". Since your first call replaced "7" with "1Mbps...", the 3rd line will replace the "1" in that sentence as well. I would recommend iterating over the array, or use some regex. One approach would be:

```
$new_data = array();

foreach( $ids as $id ) {
    switch( $id ) {
        case 1:
            $new_data[] = '3Mbps Internet';
            break;
        case 7:
            $new_data[] = '1Mbps Internet';
            break;
    }
}

//remove duplicates?
$new_data = array_unique($new_data);
```

Partial implementation, but hopefully you get the point.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I see why I'm getting the unexpected results now, totally missed that part. I'll look into what you've suggested. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While `str_replace` applies its replacements one after another (even if called once with arrays as parameter), `strtr` ("string translate") doesn't.

See [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

> If given two arguments, the second should be an array in the form `array('from' => 'to', ...)`. The return value is a string where all the occurrences of the array keys have been replaced by the corresponding values. The longest keys will be tried first. **Once a substring has been replaced, its new value will not be searched again.**

(highlight added)

So what you can do is:

```
$ids = strtr($ids, array(
    '7' => '1Mbps Internet',
    '4' => '2Mbps Internet',
    '1' => '3Mbps Internet',
    '8' => 'Commercial Internet',
    '12'=> 'Tower Friends',
    '6' => 'Cable TV',
    '11'=> 'Cable TV Basic',
    '5' => 'VOIP',
    '10', 'Web Services', $ids);
));
```